# How to get the content of a hidden sibling-div to a button - JQuery related

Tags: jquery, alert, hiddenfield

Maybe I've searched poorly, but so far I have not found the answer to my question.  First the code of the Javascript function:

```
<script>
    function showComment(){
        var $data = $(this).parent("td").contents("div.hiddenComment").text();
        console.log($data);
        alert($data);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I've also included the the HTML code I'm working on below. Basically it is a `<table>`, and in one `<td>` there is a `<button>` and a hidden `<div>`. The content of the `<div>` should be presented in an alert/dialog box.

```
<table class="center">
      <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Status</th>
             <th>Datum</th>
             <th>Zeit</th>
             <th>Amount</th>
             <th>Source</th>
             <th colspan="2">Comment</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>status1</td>
             <td>2013-04-04</td>
             <td>06:30:38</td>
             <td>3.646.268,00</td>
             <td>SRC1</td>
             <td>
                <div class="hiddenComment">a comment</div>
                <button name="showComment" type="button" href="#" class="showComment" onClick="showComment()">show</button>
             </td>
             <td><a href="#" class="addComment">add</a>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>status</td>
             <td>2013-04-05</td>
             <td>06:30:48</td>
             <td>1.732.213,00</td>
             <td>SRC2</td>
             <td>
                <div class="hiddenComment">an other comment</div>
                <button name="showComment" type="button" href="#" class="showComment" onClick="showComment()">show</button>
             </td>
             <td><a href="#" class="addComment">add</a>
             </td>
          </tr>
          .....
      </body>
</table>
```

I guess you can get the idea about the `<table>` from this code.  Anyhow, the best I achieved until now after searching the web was an `"undefined"` message.

What I should note: the class `.hiddenComment` has the CSS property `display:none`.

Any hints, tips and tricks are warmly welcome!

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a click event to the class showComment. From there you can get the previous element and get it's text.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5wQxV/1/)

```
$('.showComment').click(function(){
    alert($(this).prev().text());
    //or the below if the order of your elements might change.
    //alert($(this).siblings('.hiddenComment').text());
});
```

If any of your content is dynamicly loaded you can use a delegate:

```
$('body').on('click','.showComment',function(){
    alert($(this).prev().text()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're working with jQuery now, kill that ol'skool inline click call. Simply put, the following will work with what you have now. Remove the inline "onclick" event's and add this to your js:

```
<script>
    function showComment(event){
        var $data = $(this).parent("td").contents("div.hiddenComment").text();
        console.log($data);
        alert($data);
        return false;
    }
    $(function() {
        $("button[name=showComment]").on("click", showComment);

        //  OR with a different selector, such as a class name
        //  $(".showComment").on("click", showComment);

        //  OR asign it as a delegate, accounting for "dynamic data"
        //  $("td").on("click", "button[name=showComment]", showComment);
    }
</script>
```

## jsFiddle (<sub>working example using *YOUR* code</sub>)

Learn More About jQuery:

- [API](http://api.jquery.com/)
- [More about jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)